# how to use tf.contrib.image.rotate in loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, rotation, loss

I use the tf.conbrib.image.rotate in loss function, and an error happen:

```
No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients,
```

My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

image_tensor = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,320,320,1])
target_tensor = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,320,320,1])
s = tf.concat([image_tensor, target_tensor],axis=3)
s = tf.layers.flatten(s)
w = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([204800,1], stddev=0.1),name='w')
b = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([1], stddev=0.1),name='b')
a = tf.matmul(s,w)+b
diff = tf.contrib.image.rotate(image_tensor, a[:,0], interpolation='BILINEAR') - target_tensor
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(diff))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

My tensorflow is: 1.4.0, and my computer is Win10.

By the way, how can I rotate the 3D image in tensorflow? the tf.conbrib.image.rotate only work for 2D image.

Answer (score 0):

the tf.contrib.image.rotate cannot be optimized. I find a useful code for spatial transform network (https://github.com/kevinzakka/spatial-transformer-network).